# Best way to save history for app

Tags: android, save, calculator, history

I want to write an android calculator app like the one on my android phone. It saves history for operations and by clicking a button it shows last operations. Now my question is what is the best way to save operations? Is it reasonable to save them to a file in internal storage or what?

Comment: "I want to write a calculator app..." - What type of app? Windows, Mac, iOS, Android, WebApp, ...

Comment: It is android app @balexandre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some options..

1) Include a SQLite Database, as others mentioned. This makes storing lots of information really easy. You can find tutorials on how to include one properly in your project, and don't hvae to care for much more. You can then work with content providers to read and store data.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

2) SharedPreferences. If you just intend to store like the last, or the last 3 Operations, you can just use shared Preferences. This is way less overhead than adding a Database, if it is a small project, albeit you will have to keep your data structured yourself.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

3) If you just want to store the users *current session* you can just Keep a Stack of the used operations. On undo, or however you call it, you would just pop the stack.
By implementing `onSaveInstanceState` and `Parcelable` you can make sure that no data is lost on rotation / low memory and such.

I personally would advise you without knowing more about your project to use plain java objects and storing the state. A calculater would in most cases not need persistent storage. If you really want to know what the user did 2 weeks ago, you should use a Database.

Comment: You do not want to write to files. You will have to write too much code, to accomplish what you can do with shared preferences.

If there is more data to save, use a database, if its some strings, use preferences. Unless you really know what and why you do, there is no need to write to files.

But as I said, without knowing more about your special use case, it's hard to say.
But genereally speaking, use what you have and don't make custom implementations. Most of the times that makes things harder than they have to be.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use database(`SQLite`) for storing the data.

If you don't know more about `SQLite` in android have a look at [these](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLonJJ3BVjZW5JdoFT0Rlt3ry5Mjp7s8cT) 
tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I think database should be handy for history if more than one operations has to be stored else for one operation you can use shared preference.